# Something-Treewidth Property

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, treewidth, graph-minor

Let $s$ be a graph parameter (ex. diameter, domination number, etc)

A family $\mathcal{F}$ of graphs has the $s$-treewidth property if there is a function $f$ such that for any graph 
$G\in \mathcal{F}$, the treewidth of $G$ is at most $f(s)$.

For instance, let $s = \mathit{diameter}$, and $\mathcal{F}$ be the family of planar graphs. Then it is known that any planar graph of diameter at most $s$ has treewidth at most $O(s)$.
More generally, [Eppstein](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s004530010020) showed that a family of graphs has the diameter-treewidth property if and only if it excludes some apex graph as a minor.
Examples of such families are graphs of constant genus, etc.

As another example, let $s = \mathit{domination{-}number}$. [Fomin and Thilikos](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-39658-1_22) have proved an analog result to Eppstein's by showing that a family of graphs has the domination-number-treewidth property
if and only if $\mathcal{F}$ has local-treewidth. Note that this happens if and only if $\mathcal{F}$ has the diameter-treewidth property.

**Questions:**

1. For which graph parameters $s$ is the $s$-treewidth property known to hold on planar graphs?
2. For which graph parameters $s$ is the $s$-treewidth property known to hold on graphs of bounded local-treewidth?
3. Are there any other families of graphs, not comparable to graphs of bounded local-treewidth for which the $s$-treewidth property holds for some suitable parameter $s$?

I have a feeling that these questions have some relation with the theory of [bidimensionality](http://publications.csail.mit.edu/abstracts/abstracts07/demaine_bidim/demaine_bidim.html). Within this theory,
there are several important parameters. For instance, the sizes of feedback vertex set, vertex cover,
minimum maximal matching, face cover, dominating set, edge dominating set,
R-dominating set, connected dominating set, connected edge dominating set,
connected R-dominating set, etc.

4. Does any parameter $s$ encountered in bidimensionality theory have the $s$-treewidth property for some suitable family of graphs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For question $1$: any *bidimensional* parameter has this property on general graphs. A parameter $s(G)$ is bidimensional if the value of $s(G) \geq s(H)$ for every minor $H$ of $G$, and if $s$ is ``large'' on grids.

In applications to PTASes, sub exponential algorithms and kernels on minor-free classes of graphs, "large" means that there exists a constant $c$, such that the value of $s$ on a $t$ times $t$ grid is at least $ct^2$. This is what you most likely will find if you do a google search for ``bidimensionality''

However, for your question it is sufficient that $s$ grows to infinity on $t$ times $t$ grids as $t$ grows to infinity. This is because any graph with large enough treewidth will contain a large enough grid minor. So, to conclude, if $s$:

- is closed under minors
- is arbitrarily large on $t$ times $t$ grids for large enough $t$

Then s has the s-treewidth property. See the recent parameterized complexity book ( http://parameterized-algorithms.mimuw.edu.pl ) in the treewidth chapter for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Among your list, (at least) vertex cover number and feedback vertex set size, for graphs in general.

1. If a graph has a vertex cover of size at most $s$, then it has treewidth at most $\dots$ ?
2. If a graph has a feedback vertex set of size at most $s$, then it has treewidth at most $\dots$ ?